# NSDate time or !time in it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

Is it possible to see on a *NSDate* whether the time part has been set or not?

Or to rephrase the question: is it possible to create a *NSDate* in such a way that when I look at the instance I can see whether the time was set or not?

I am having an issue where I read sometimes *DATE* and sometimes *DATETIME* from a database. In both cases I create a *NSDate* object however I would like to know what the original type was. I know I can do a wrapper or something around the *NSDate* but I just wondering if there is some other simpler way by just looking at the *NSDate* instance to see whether the time was set or not originally?

tia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you are creating your NSDate instances the same way, just with hours, minutes and seconds set to 0 in the *DATE* only case, converting that to a NSTimeInterval and using that to initialize your date?

Then, there is no way to distinguish a real date and a false one. You can check using the same algorithm you used to create it, i.e. are hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0. But this will fail for a real *DATETIME* with those properties - which might or might not be a problem.

As far as documentation tells, there is no way to set a date only, so your convertion already introduces this loss of detail.

Answer (score 2):

An `NSDate` represents a single point in time.  As such, it will *always* have a time associated with it.  Therefore, your question is invalid.  If you have an `NSDate`, then it has a time component.  If you want to extract various portions of the date (such as the month, year, hour, second, etc), then you'll use [`-[NSCalendar components:fromDate:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-BBCCAFIG).